# How to limit the height of MUI Autocomplete input box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, textfield

I am having trouble in limiting the height of MUI Autocomplete component. When I select the value from the list it automatically add empty space or row at the bottom of input which I do not want.

Below is my example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-n8nc6i?file=/src/App.js

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yWf5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bypass the default css style from MUI, then you can use inside your css the following:

```
.MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot {
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-rh0e4p)

Comment: Also if text is long then we have to handle the chips width as well. .MuiAutocomplete-tag{
    max-width: 80px !important;
}

Comment: yes indeed! i only changed the part of extra space below :)

Comment: Thanks. It works but the chips were overflowing outside the textfield when clicked. So I added another class. .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot {
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.Mui-focused{
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this with:

```js
MuiAutocomplete: {
  styleOverrides: {
      inputRoot: {
          '&:not(.Mui-focused)': {
              flexWrap: 'nowrap',
          },
      },
  },
},
```

Comment: Hi Giedrius, can you add some explanation as to why this fixes the issue?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).